# How to evaluate mathematical formula consist of string?

Tags: php, math, eval, mathematical-optimization

In mm project i want to evaluate mathematical formula which is a string. Example: `"((1*10)/100) + 100"`.

How can evaluate such formula? I used `eval()` but it is throwing `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file` error and `eval` is not a safe function to use.

Is that anyway if i can do that? And if there is no way except eval then how should i do it? Why it thrown  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file` error?

Comment: `exec()` allows to execute commands, not to compute the result of a mathematical equation. That is something completely different. That string does not contain any commands, so no valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

php's [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function allows to execute *commands*, not to compute the result of a mathematical equation or formula. That is something completely different. That string does not contain any commands, so it is not valid syntax.

Instead you need to feed a valid *command* into your call to `exec()` instead of a mathematical formula:

Have a look at this simple example:

```
<?php
$input = '((1*10)/100) + 100';
echo exec('php -r "echo ' . $input . ';"');
```

This obviously requires a command line version of php being available as `php` in case you try to trigger that from within a http server. But the same certainly can be done using any other available interpreter, for example `bash`.

An "inline" alternative (so without forking an external process) is to use php's [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)  function. But again you need to feed it a command, not a formula. The advantage is that you do not have to rely on any other tool or interpreter to be usable at run time. The corresponding example would be:

```
<?php
$input = '((1*10)/100) + 100';
echo eval('return ' . $input . ';');
```

The output of both snippets obviously is `100.1`.

Note however that it is crucial for both approaches to have complete control over what formula you feed into the execution. Do *not* allow client side input to pass into this unfiltered! That would allow any attacker to execute arbitrary code on your system!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
echo eval('return '. "((1*10)/100) + 100" .';');
```